# in node.js, socket.io using redis - is this redis available for nomal redis use?

Tags: node.js, redis, socket.io

my understanding is that `socket.io` uses `redis`

```
socket.set( 'var', val1 );
var val2 = socket.get( 'var' );
```

but `redis` is not in `node_modules`

does `socket.io` use its own private instance of `redis`?  if not, is is possible, through a redis client, to access `socket.io` values stored in `redis`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redis is used by Socket.io to store information about sockets. You need to use it if you have several socket.io servers for the same application.

Obviously you can use this redis for your application if you don't override the data of socket.io.

Socket.io uses the publish/subscribe functionality of redis (see [documentation](https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO/wiki/Configuring-Socket.IO)), not the key/value store.

Comment: perfect.  what would be the difference between using `var redis = require("redis"),...` and `var redis = require('socket.io/lib/stores/redis'),...`?

Comment: @ccyoung no difference (except if they're different versions). However, it's standard practice in the node.js community to state your dependencies, i.e. your app has it's own redis library in `node_modules`, and any dependencies have their own, in their respective `node_modules`.

Comment: I would also use `var redis = require("redis")` because you can't be sure that socket.io will always depends on redis.